# Replicate Git Repository

Tags: git, ubuntu, repository, replication, gerrit

We've got a Gerrit service running on a Ubuntu server with a few Git repositories over there.

Everything that we do needs to be backed up somewhere on a server located in our network.

We can't store the repositories over there and only use that server as the connection to it is fairly slow.

I have done some research and I found a couple of ways of doing this, but still I'm not exactly sure if these are up to date and how exactly I'm supposed to do this.

Sorry but I really need some help.

Comment: rsync? cron job with scp? Whichever's the easiest (and most secure, if required) way to set it up to be honest. Difficult to say more without knowing what kind of setup you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interesed in [Gerrit Replication](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/replication/) plugin and its [docs](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/replication/+/master/src/main/resources/Documentation).

Comment: That's what we tried and managed to succeed using in the end. Although the information I found wasn't that easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular backups like rsync or you can use the replication plugin that automatically synchronize on changes to a remote git repository (that can only be use as backup).